# Drag an Drop an Image to an AIR App

Tags: actionscript-3, drag-and-drop, air

I have a Flash stage with an image on it. Now I like to change this image by dragging and dropping an other image from a random OS folder. Has anybody an idea how this works?

Comment: Basics of drag and drop in AIR @ http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7d85.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demostration is here: http://take.ms/8rJ9j

```
package {

    import flash.desktop.ClipboardFormats;
    import flash.desktop.NativeDragManager;
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.NativeDragEvent;
    import flash.filesystem.File;
    import flash.filesystem.FileMode;
    import flash.filesystem.FileStream;
    import flash.utils.ByteArray;

    public class DragApp extends Sprite
    {
        private var target:Sprite;
        private var moveBitmap:Bitmap;
        private var loader:Loader;
        public function DragApp()
        {
            target = new Sprite();
            target.graphics.lineStyle(1, 0x0, 1);
            target.graphics.beginFill(0xffffff, 1);
            target.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
            target.x = 100;
            target.y = 100;
            this.addChild(target);
            //
            moveBitmap = new Bitmap();
            moveBitmap.x = target.x;
            moveBitmap.y = target.y;
            this.addChild(moveBitmap);
            //
            loader = new Loader();
            //
            target.addEventListener(NativeDragEvent.NATIVE_DRAG_ENTER, dragEnterHandler);
        }

        private var currentFile:File;
        private function dragEnterHandler(event:NativeDragEvent):void
        {
            moveBitmap.bitmapData = null;
            //
            var files:Array = event.clipboard.getData(ClipboardFormats.FILE_LIST_FORMAT) as Array;
            currentFile = files[0];
            var arrPath:Array = currentFile.name.split('.');
            var type:String = arrPath[arrPath.length-1];
            if (!currentFile.isDirectory && (type == 'png' || type == 'jpg')) {
                NativeDragManager.acceptDragDrop(target);
                //
                var stream:FileStream = new FileStream();
                stream.open(currentFile, FileMode.READ);
                var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
                stream.readBytes(bytes);
                stream.close();
                //
                loader.loadBytes(bytes);
                loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadCompleteHandler);
                //
                target.addEventListener(NativeDragEvent.NATIVE_DRAG_OVER, dragOverHandler);
                target.addEventListener(NativeDragEvent.NATIVE_DRAG_DROP, dragDropHandler);
                target.addEventListener(NativeDragEvent.NATIVE_DRAG_EXIT, dragExitHandler);
            }
        }
        private function loadCompleteHandler(event:Event):void
        {
            var content:Bitmap = (loader.content) as Bitmap;
            moveBitmap.bitmapData = content.bitmapData;
            moveBitmap.width = target.width;
            moveBitmap.height = target.height;
            moveBitmap.smoothing = true;
            moveBitmap.alpha = 0.8;
        }
        private function dragOverHandler(event:NativeDragEvent):void
        {

        }
        private function dragDropHandler(event:NativeDragEvent):void
        {
            moveBitmap.alpha = 1;
            //
            target.removeEventListener(NativeDragEvent.NATIVE_DRAG_OVER, dragOverHandler);
            target.removeEventListener(NativeDragEvent.NATIVE_DRAG_DROP, dragDropHandler);
            target.removeEventListener(NativeDragEvent.NATIVE_DRAG_EXIT, dragExitHandler);
        }
        private function dragExitHandler(event:NativeDragEvent):void
        {
            moveBitmap.bitmapData = null;
            //
            target.removeEventListener(NativeDragEvent.NATIVE_DRAG_OVER, dragOverHandler);
            target.removeEventListener(NativeDragEvent.NATIVE_DRAG_DROP, dragDropHandler);
            target.removeEventListener(NativeDragEvent.NATIVE_DRAG_EXIT, dragExitHandler);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Basically it works. thank you so much. But does it also work with an movieclip instead of a sprite?

Comment: It work with all [InteractiveObject](http://help.adobe.com/en_EN/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/InteractiveObject.html) and his descendants (Sprite, MovieClip, TextField, Stage ...)

Comment: I could solve the issue: I placed an MC on my stage and set on the eventlistener. thanks again!